# external data formatting strips off leading zero

Tags: excel

I am using excel 2003 and importing an external data source from an asp page.

This page returns a table of data that populates the excel cells.

If a cell has a phone number in it, the leading zero is removed by excel, although if I look at the query in the import dialog, the zero is still there!

The cells have been formatted as "text" in the hope this would not happen, but still the text gets treated as a number!

Any ideas? I could really do with some help on this one.

Comment: Prepend a single quote before putting the text into the cell. This lets Excel know that it's a text value. IOW, assign `'012-34-4432` (note the leading single quote).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my asp code to add a ' before each item, and this sort of works, but now every field has the ' showing.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. If the leading character is a single quote, it tells Excel to format the cell as text. (You can try it yourself in Excel. Type a number with a leading zero into a cell, and the zero is removed. Type the same number with a leading single quote before the 0 digit, and the zero remains.) Do you have any spaces to the left of the quote?

Comment: It's to do with the importing of the external data I think. If I select a cell that has the ' showing and then click into the edit bar to edit the text, and then click away, the ' disappears and the leading zero displays correctly. Or, if I double click the cell and then click away, the ' also disappears and the leading zero displays correctly! This is really weird.

Comment: I've seen this happen before, if Dave enters the cell (F2) and presses enter the apostrophe will go away. For my application it didn't matter though, so I don't have a solution for you.

Comment: +1 to Jon49's comment, suggest you try this. If this works we can provide code (usin variant arrays) that will automate this "refresh" for you

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, changing the NumberFormat to text should work.  If you're dealing with a fixed-width cell (i.e., 10 digits for a phone number), you can manually prepend leading zeros.  Assuming data is in column A, put this formula into column B

```
=right("000000000"&A1,10)
```

You can then copy and PasteSpecial into column A.

If the cells are not fixed width and If you have access to the query that populates the asp page, you can insert a temporary column that has the desired cell length and use that to modify the function.

Likewise, if you're just looking to display the information and you don't need to act on it, you can put a number mask over the cell (Format Cell->Custom->0000000000).

As for upgrading, I am currently using Excel 2007 and constantly import data with prepended zeros by making the specific column a Text field.